# How to check duplicate values in a list of objects

Tags: java, spring-mvc, java-6

I have a Spring MVC application  where I need to save a list of persons. However I need to check if the name,surname and age are the same among 
the list of person. If there are the same then I should stop the user from saving the data
The **Person** class has the following attributes:

```
int id, String name ,String surname,int age -- with getters and setters
```

I have another class call **GroupModel** that contains a list of Person as follows:

```
List <Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

So now I need to check for the following scenarios where the user is trying to save the following list:

If I have 3 person in the persons list:

- Person 1 : id: 1,name:John Surname:Joe Age:21
- Person 2 : id: 2,name:Ryan Surname:Ter Age:23
- Person 3 : id: 3,name:John Surname:Joe Age:21

I need to check for duplication in that case Person 1 and Person 3 are the same then stop the user from saving the list.
So any idea how can I carry out the check for duplication in that case please?

Comment: Create a Set from the List and see if it has the same length. If equals is not properly implemented for persons, create a set from the names or ids and compare that.

Comment: override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in `Person` class

Comment: @tobias_k told you the right answer

Comment: Use Set instead of List. Override equals() method in your Person class which will check for name, surname and age.

Comment: @NikhilJoshi - He will also habe to override `hashCode()` if he overrides `equals()`

Comment: Agree, hashCode() as well.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `equals` (and `hashCode`) for `Person`, so two objects are equal if the 3 attributes are equal. Then, create a temporary `Set` from the `ArrayList`. If the set has fewer elements than the list, you have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Override method `boolean equals(Object obj)`. This method should return true if fields: name,surname and age will be the same on both object and object will be instanceOf Person.
Then call boolean contains(Object o) method from List class. This method will check if your list contains object, which is equals to object given as parametr.

I think this is one of the best way.

Answer (score 0):

```
package stackoverflow.q_24935480;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class TestPersonInSet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Person> s = new HashSet<Person>();
        Person p1 = new Person(); p1.setName("abc");
        Person p2 = new Person(); p2.setName("abc");
        s.add(p1);
        s.add(p2);
        System.out.println("Set size is " + s.size());
    }

    static class Person {
        private String name;

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Person other = (Person) obj;
            if (name == null) {
                if (other.name != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

    }
}

//Output: 
//Set size is 1
```